How to simulate a click on a specific node in the visNetwork graph?
I need to simulate a click on a specific node in a visNetwork graph in a Shiny application, I have to use JavaScript as app$executeScript() function in my Shiny test. This is what I get if I type in the console
'HTMLWidgets.find('#process_genealogy-network_output')


The specific JS code is the following:
app$executeScript(
  "
  // Access the visNetwork instance by widget ID
  var network = HTMLWidgets.find('#process_genealogy-network_output');

  // Simulate a click on the node with a specific ID
  network.setSelection({nodes: ['3027356-24']});
  network.emit('click', {
      nodes: ['3027356-24'],
      edges: []
  });
  "
)

Instead, this is the visNetwork line:
output$network_output <- renderVisNetwork({..})
I called process_genealogy-network_output because process_genealogy is the module of my app.

There are some strange things with the shinytest package and htmlwidgets. See e.g. this unsolved issue.  Have you tried to run HTMLWidgets.find('#process_genealogy-network_output') in the browser console? Does it work? And please provide a full but minimal code when you require some help. Finally, the shinytest package is deprecated, one has to use shinytest2 nowadays.

You wrote genealogy and geneaology.
